# How can I send AT commands to HM-10 module from my android phone?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-leonardo

Earlier today, I was able to connect flawlessly to my HM-10 module via the Arduino serial monitor. I think I then changed some settings without thinking and now I can no longer connect to it. No errors, nothing. I have tried every baud setting but to no avail. I am able to connect to it through my Android phone but is there an app where I can send AT commands just like the Arduino serial monitor. I'm thinking I could do this to run the at+reset command to factory reset it? Are there any other ways of resetting the module?

Comment: what does this mean? `changed some settings`

Comment: No. You are the wrong end of the connection. Like trying to turn a light on by squeezing the bulb (sorry, I'm usually the king of analogies, but I have come down with a cold and I can't come up with anything even remotely realistic...)

Comment: @jsotola Through the arduino serial monitor, I was playing with at+type, at+baud and at+mode.

Comment: @Majenko So is there a way of hard resetting the board then?